# HTTP Status Code for Resource with Multiple URIs

Tags: rest, http

Which HTTP status code should be used when redirecting from a secondary URL to a primary URL?

For example, if the "official" URL of a Contact page is `/contact-us` and I want to provide `/contact` as a shorthand convenience, what would be the appropriate status code?

Answer (score 1):

Use one of these:

- 301 Moved Permanently
- 302 Found
- 303 See Other

From your question I think [`303 See other`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303) is most appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I was scared off by 303 after reading this from the page you linked: "A 303 response to a GET request indicates that the origin server does not have a representation of the target resource that can be transferred by the server over HTTP." However it does seem to be the best available option.

Comment: @cantera 303 is appropriate for most use cases. 301 is actually problematic here - the client may establish a permanent association from `/contact` to `/contact-us`, but obviously you don't want that to be permanent.